# Template class destructors

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple template class in c++. I've been trying to compile the following but I only get a compile error. This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

template<int size>
class array {
public:
    int len;
    int data[size];
    array(void) : len(size) {}
    virtual ~array(void) {}
};

int main() {
    array<3> a;
    for (int i=0; i < a.len; ++i) {
        a.data[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", a.data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error g++-4.2.1 is giving me:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "__Unwind_Resume", referenced from:
      _main in ccaYob9x.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If we comment out the line for the destructor then the code compiles as it should and it gives me a list of the number 0, 1, 2.

What my ultimate goal is after understanding how template base classes work is to create specialized template classes. I want to create a multidimensional array but I wish to specialize it for the cases when the dimension is 1, 2, and 3. I mainly want to be able to overload the `operator()` for those cases. In any case, using a template class like this saves me the trouble of allocating memory dynamically when the dimensions are 1, 2, and 3. Does someone know how to change the code to allocate memory dynamically? Doing so will require you to define the destructor, which is the problem I'm currently facing.

**EDIT:**

I'm not familiar with template specialization. Does someone know how to make a specialized template when size=1, 2 and 3 to have static memory for data and by default to have dynamic memory?

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that I'm having trouble due to my g++ compiler. Does anyone see anything with with this:

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-  werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple- darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

**EDIT 3:**

There has got to be something wrong with my g++ version. I just tried it with g++4.0 in the same machine and with the macports version g++-mp-4.3 and it works fine. I guess it is time to upgrade to the next version. Thank you for your answers and hints.

Comment: `func(void)` is a C-ism, in C++ it would be `func()` instead.

Comment: Using `bar foo(void);` in a declaration is for C. In C++ the correct way is `bar foo();` instead. While in C empty parenthesis means "i dont't want to tell you what the parameters are" in C++ the meaning is "there are no parameters".

Comment: @K-ballo, I removed the void from both the constructor and destructor but I still get the same compiler error.

Comment: @6502, see the comment directed to K-ballo.

Comment: @jmlopez: Yeah, that was not an answer to your question, but a comment on general C++ coding styles.

Comment: @jmlopez: It was just a general comment. I don't seen anything formally wrong in the code (just IMO bad choices and form) and indeed it works as expected on my system.

Comment: @6502... good thing I brought it up here then. I just remembered I still have g++-4.0 and also the the macports version. It works fine... in those two. Well, at least I learned useful things from the comments and the two answers provided.

Comment: @jmlopez: if `array` is not used as a base class, you don't need a virtual destructor.

Comment: @jmlopez: In C++, use iostreams, not printf/scanf.

Comment: @jmlopez: the C++ way to include C-headers is `#include <cstdio>` and `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: @jmlopez: it is redundant to store a compile time value (size) in a runtime variable, you can use `enum { len = size };` instead

Comment: it's working find under gcc4.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
template<int size>
class array {
public:
    int len;
    int *data;
    array();
    virtual ~array(void);
};

// 1 dimension specialized array 
template <>
array<1>::array() : len(1)
{
    data = new int;
}

template <>
array<1>::~array()
{
    delete data;
}

template <int size>
array<size>::array() : len(size)
{
data = new int[size];
} 

template <int size>
array<size>::~array()
{
delete [] data;
}

int main(int, char)
{
    array<3> a;
    for (int i=0; i < a.len; ++i) {
        a.data[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", a.data[i]);
    }

    array<1> b;
    for (int i=0; i < b.len; ++i) {
        b.data[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", b.data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With g++ you will not have compiling errors. You can define specialized operator() for each different array sizes without problems, like constructor and destructor seams.

Comment: Thank you, you had answer what I had written in the edit a few seconds after I posted it. I tried it in my machine but I still get the same error: `Undefined symbols: "__Unwind_Resume"`. I'm using OS X 10.6 by way. I did try your code in a linux machine with g++ version 4.5.1 and it works. What do I need to do to make it work in my mac? upgrade g++?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you about OS X. I don't know if this is an obsolete g++ problem. I don't think so because I'm working with a very old g++ version, exactly (GCC) 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42). Post your compiling and linking parameters and we'll check them. Perhaps refers to another code portion.

Comment: -1: seriously, why do you want to allocate dynamically if the size is known at compile time? and new T[1] would be perfectly fine if you really want dynamic allocation. [edit: -1 removed, just seen the OPs edit]

Answer (score 1):

This is not stricly related to the question, but let me give you some int hints about yiour code.

First: decide if you want to use C or C++. Templates are C++, but you are "coding as a C programmer". Not that this is bad by itself, bu it is out out context. (use `iostream`, not `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h`, don't use `function(void)` but just `function()`). 
May be it's not your case, but check also your source doesn't have "C" extension (this may fool the compiler) and use g++ (not gcc) as a command (the library you'll link are different)

Second: pay attention about the use of variables and constant: the `inst size` as a template parameter, when instantiated is constant. There in no clue in keeping a `len` variable (in your design, the array size cannot be changed): a `static const int len = size` is all what you need.

Third: if you really want to test, don't use a single `for` loop to assign and read values: this makes you completely blind in case of indexes misuse: instead of `a.data[i]` try the wrong `a.data[0]` and you'll get exactly the same output. Use a loop to fill the array, followed by another loop to read from it.

Fourth: In C++, scopes are important: keep open and closing braces {} aligned. This may sound pedantic, but saved me soooo many times....

Comment: I am using g++ as my command. the stdlib.h is a bad habit I have. I'll try to get rid of it. I really liked your second point. This is something that I needed at some point but I never figured I could do it the way you mentioned. 3: I usually do that but I was trying to keep the example short.